VSCode Matplotlib plots in a different window [Ubuntu]
I've switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 23.10.
I noticed that in VSCode for Ubuntu, my Python Matplotlib plots are created as VSCode windows.
Whereas, in Windows, they are separate from VSCode which is useful for visualization and closing the separate windows without plenty of clicking.
Does anyone know if it's a VSCode setting or Matplotlib configuration I need to set?
I've tried using TkAgg / QtAgg backend for Matplotlib which yields the same results.


